# Nested vector<float> and reference manipulation

Tags: c++, vector, reference

final edit: I got it!

```
//Initialize each collection using pointers

array<float, 3> monster1 = { 10.5, 8.5, 1.0 }; //coordinates and direction of first monster
array<float, 3> monster2 = { 13.5, 1.5, 2.0 }; //coordinates and direction of second monster
array<float, 3> monster3 = { 4.5, 6.5, 3.0 }; //coordinates and direction of third monster
array<float, 3> monster4 = { 2.5, 13.5, 4.0 }; //coordinates and direction of fourth monster

vector<array<float,3>*> pinkys = { &monster1 };
vector<array<float, 3>*> blinkys = { &monster2 };
vector<array<float, 3>*> inkys = { &monster3 };
vector<array<float, 3>*> clydes = { &monster4 };

vector<vector<array<float,3>*>*> all_ghosts = { &pinkys, &blinkys, &inkys, &clydes };

...

//Function definition

void updateMonster(array<float, 3>& monster);

...

//appropriate for loop and function call

void display() {
    if (!over) {
            
        for (auto list : all_ghosts) {
            for (auto ghost : *list) {
                updateMonster(*ghost);
            }
            }
}
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION BELOW**:

I'm trying to modify a [C++ pacman project](https://github.com/patriciateroltolsa/Pacman/blob/master/assign10.cpp) where the ghosts are defined as float arrays:

```
float* monster1 = new float[3]{ 10.5, 8.5, 1.0 }; //coordinates and direction of first monster
...
float* monster4 = new float[3]{ 2.5, 13.5, 4.0 }; //coordinates and direction of fourth monster
```

Currently they are being updated successfully one-by-one by a function :

```
void updateMonster(float* monster) { ... }
```

That's called as:

```
void display() {
    ...
        if (!over) {
            
            updateMonster(monster1);
            updateMonster(monster2);
            updateMonster(monster3);
            updateMonster(monster4);
            
        }
    ...
}
```

My goal is to instead add the original monsters to a `vector<float*>` so that I can iterate through them in a for loop and update them:

```
static vector<float*> v = { monster1, monster2, monster3, monster4 };
...

void display() {
    ...
        if (!over) {
            
            for (auto* m : v) {
                updateMonster(m);
            }
            
        }
    ...
}
```

However, it hasn't worked successfully in a for loop. Where are my references/pointers going wrong? Thanks!

Edit:
I should've mentioned that I wanted to have my collection of monsters grow and decrease in size, thus needing a vector. My problem though is that when I declare them as such:

```
float* monster1 = new float[3]{ 10.5, 8.5, 1.0 }; //coordinates and direction of first monster
...
static vector<float*> v = { monster1, monster2, monster3, monster4 };
```

It doesn't work as I expect when I iterate through them as:

```
for (auto& m : v) {
                updateMonster(m);
            }
```

([my progress](https://github.com/jibranabsarulislam/VaxMan-cpp-/blob/master/VaxManCPP/main.cpp))

Comment: If the number of "monsters" is known at compile-time, why not an array of arrays? As in `std::array<std::array<float, 3>, 4>`? Or if you need to add more "monsters" at run-time a vector of arrays `std::vector<std::array<float, 3>>`? Please try to avoid pointers and direct explicit memory handling.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude, yes I should've mentioned that my goal is to add more monsters at any given point. I've added some edits to my question regarding those changes.

Comment: One almost *never* need pointers to containers (like `std::vector` or `std::array`). One of the nice things about C++ and its standard containers is that it's a simple way to avoid pointers, as pointers could be prone to errors and mistakes, as well as needing extra syntactic operators to be able to use the objects being pointed to. For example if you have a pointer to an array `arr` you no longer can  do `arr[i]` but must do either `arr->operator[](i)` or `(*arr)[i]` or similar.

Comment: If you really need to be able to "reference" the original vectors and arrays, use [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) and corresponding [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) to store actual references instead.

Comment: A side note, I would suggest to use a `struct` or a `class` instead of an `array` for the monster if you aren't intended to loop over the items in that array. And if there are only 4 direction to choose from, use a `enum` for it. And make `update` a member function of `struct monster`: https://godbolt.org/z/5rodcahb1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std::array`. No need to use raw pointers:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using Monster = std::array<float, 3>;

void updateMonster(Monster& monster);

int main() {
  std::vector<Monster> monsters;

  monsters.push_back(Monster{1.f, 2.f, 3.f});
  monsters.push_back(Monster{4.f, 5.f, 6.f});
  monsters.push_back(Monster{7.f, 8.f, 9.f});

  for (auto& monster : monsters) updateMonster(monster);
}
```

[<kbd>Godbolt</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/e6sc44Kaf)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I should've mentioned earlier that I want the collection of monsters to grow thus needing a vector of the float arrays. Please see the edits to my question

Comment: @JibranAbsarulislam if this is better

Comment: Yes, I ran into some problems with the way I edited above, but I used your method and it worked well. Thanks again