# Adding a new instance of an array to a vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, reference, instance

This is a continuation of my previous question: [Nested vector<float> and reference manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68343217/).

I got the loops and all working, but I'm trying to add new instances of arrays to a total vector.

Here's one example of what I mean:

```cpp
array<float, 3> monster1 = { 10.5, 8.5, 1.0 };
// ...
vector<array<float, 3>*> pinkys = { &monster1};
// ...
void duplicateGhosts() {

    int count = 0; 
    int i = pinkys.size(); // this line and previous avoid overflow

    array<float, 3>& temp = monster1; // this gets the same data, but right now it's just a reference

    for (auto monster : pinkys) { // for each array of floats in the pinkys vector,
        if (count >= i)           // if in this instance of duplicateGhosts they've all been pushed back,
            break;                
        pinkys.push_back(&temp);  // this is where I want to push_back a new instance of an array
        count++;
    }
}
```

With the current code, instead of creating a new `monster`, it is adding a reference to the original `monster1` and therefore affecting its behavior.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using array pointers (`array<float, 3>*`) in your vector rather than just arrays (`array<float, 3>`)?

Comment: Along with that, if you do that change, your entire function can become `pinkys.insert(pinkys.end(), pinkys.size(), monster1);`

Comment: You can't add or remove objects from a container you are iterating over with a range-based for loop. It invalidates the iterators the loop is using internally.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, certain behaviors weren't working unless I pointed them to previous references. I got it working though. My changes will be merged into my master branch shortly: [my repo](https://github.com/jibranabsarulislam/VaxMan-cpp-/blob/master/VaxManCPP/main.cpp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment you cannot insert elements to a container you are iterating with a range based for loop. That is because the range based for loop stops when it reaches `pinkys.end()` but that iterator gets invalidated once you call `pinkys.push_back()`. It is not clear why you are iterating `pinkys` in the first place. You aren't using `monster` (a copy of the elements in the vector) in the loop body.

The whole purpose of the loop seems to be to have as many iterations as there are already elements in the container. For that you need not iterate elements of `pinkys` but you can do:

```
 auto old_size = pinkys.size();
 for (size_t i=0; i < old_size; ++i) {
      // add elements
 }
```

Further, it is not clear why you are using a vector of pointers. Somebody has to own the monsters in the vector. If it isnt anybody else, it is the vector. And in that case you should use a `std::vector<monster>`. For shared ownership you should use `std::shared_ptr`. Never use owning raw pointers!

Don't use a plain array for something that you can give a better name:

```
 struct monster {
      float hitpoints;  // or whatever it actually is.
      float attack;     // notice how this is much clearer
      float defense;    // than using an array?
 };
```

With those modifications the method could look like this:

```
void duplicateGhosts() {
     auto old_size = pinkys.size();
     for (size_t i=0; i < old_size; ++i) {
         pinkys.push_back( pinkys[i] );
     }       
}
```

From the name of the method I assumed you want to duplciate the vectors elements. If you want to just add the same `monster` as many times as there were elements before, that is

```
void duplicateGhosts() {
     auto old_size = pinkys.size();
     for (size_t i=0; i < old_size; ++i) {
         pinkys.push_back( monster{} );
     }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understand the change from iterating each monster to instead iterating for size. It'd probably help in performance too if I didn't "access" the monster but instead an int. In response to you using `struct`, would this be the same as doing something like `using Monster = array<float, 3>`?